Enriques' principle of degeneration
It is remarked here that Zariski's connectedness theorem is based / or vast generalizating & formalizating the so called "principle of degeneration" introduced by Federigo Enriques, which says roughly that a limit of absolutely irreducible cycles is absolutely connected.
The philosophy should be plausible: We impose certain conditions on general fibre of a family $f:X \to S$ (base normal, or unibranch) and expect that the "limit fibre" (in sense of if $X_{s}$ for $s \in S - s_0$ are absolutely irreducible, then $X_{s_0}$ absolutely connected.
Question: Are there publication where Enriques originally discussed this principle? My motivation is that Zariski insisted on properness for $f$ and my question is what Enriques assumed instead. Are there say "toy" examples from which Enriques principle of degenerations essentially arose?

Enriques devoted to the principles of degeneration an article in 1922, Il principio di degenerazione e la geometria sopra le curve algebriche, https://www.federigoenriques.org/wp-content/uploads/opere/pdf/GM_Enriques_1922_1.pdf I don't know if it has been translated in English, I could't find a translation.

@BakerStreet: Can be seen in the text what Enriques precisely calls "principle of degeneration", especially which basic assumptions he made on involved objects? ( ie basic assumptions on the variety where the members of the linear system "live" (smooth, projective?), the members of the linear system (always projective?) and the base" parameter space"? Could you maybe quote the passage?

I’m sorry, but I am not an expert of algebraic geometry and in addition the language of the Italian algebraic geometry school is complex.  I can’t translate the paper, Enriques talks about the principles of degeneration in the first part of it, but I don’ know if it is necessary to read the whole article to understand what he means. Moreover, this article is a part of a big work of many volumes by Enriques and Chisini.
The algebraic geometry of the Italian school is difficult to read in the original texts, because has a difficult not standard language.

If these issues about Enriques are important to you, you can contact Ciro Ciliberto, who is full professor of algebraic geometry in Rome Tor Vergata. He is  an expert of the Italian geometric school also from an historical point of view, and an expert of the particular language of that school.

You can find his email address also at the end of this paper, written together with others  scholars of algebraic geometry https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.07142, so I think it is his current address. A reference to the principles of degeneration is also in these notes of a talk with Ciliberto as co-author https://people.dm.unipi.it/dadderio/galati-talk2.pdf

Anyway, looking at the Enriques' articolo, I can't see explicit references to the assumption you mentioned, as the assumption of projective or smooth varieties.

In an article of 1923 of the Bollettino dell’Unione Matematica Italiana,  the Enriques’ Principles of degeneration is summarised as follows (p. 145, ‘Geometria numerativa’) http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=BUMI_1923_1_2_4_140_0 :
“Seguendo il metodo di degenerazione modificato dall’Enriques
come segue: interpretato il problema numerativo come problema
di serie lineari, si lascia invariata la curva, indifferentemente
piana o sghemba, e si fa variare la serie lineare. questo metodo,
[…] offre il vantaggio, su quello di degenerazione della curva di De-Jonquières e di Castelnuovo…”

My translation:
“Following the method of degeneration modified by Enriques in the following way: once interpreted the numerative problem as a problem of linear series, the curve is left unchanged, indifferently plane or skew, and the linear series is varied. This method […] has the advantage, with respect to the method of De-Jonqiuères and of Castelnuovo….”
(I don’t know the exact translation of ‘numerativo’ in English, so I translated ‘numerative’).

@BakerStreet: Do you have an idea to which "curve" this excerpt refers? The upshot of the story with linear system goes roughly as follows: If we have a nice enough variety $X$ (mostly integral, separable, regular in codim 1) and pick a line bundle $L$ on it then we can consider the $\Bbb C$-vec space of global sections $\Gamma(X,L)$ and the so called  vanishing locus $V(s) \subset X$ of members $s \in \Gamma(X,L)$ forms a codim 1 subvariety. So the vanishing loci $V(s)$ vary when we vary the sections $s$ - one can show also that scaling $s$ not changes $V(s)$, so one can think of the

subvarieties $V(s)$ as varying family of codim 1 subvars parametrized by projectivized $\Gamma(X,L)$.
Surely one can associate to each $V(s)$ certain numerical invariants (eg dimension of global sections of regular fcts, or genera, if $V(s)$ are curves) and ask natural question how it changes if we vary $s$. The degeration principle should say that these not changes.

But what I not understand, is to which curve the text you translated is refering to. Do you have an idea?

In the Bulletin I quoted (it is a numer of the journal devoted to a review of the literature) there is just a summary of an article that speaks of the principle of degeneration, to understand to which curve it refers one should  read the original article.

I can try to search for this article.

No, I can't find the original article on internet, at the moment. The article is of Vittoria Notari, who was assistant and collaborator of Enriques at the university of Rome.

If you want I can translate the first page or so of the article by Enriques, but I am not sure that the English terminology would be correct.

@BakerStreet: I would be very grateful to you for your effort. Does this also more or less adress the issue with this "curve left unchanged" from the excerpt you previously translated?

I don't know, because the excerpt is a very short summary of that paper of Vittoria Notari.  May be you can understand the point from Enriques article, as you know algebraic geometry, I don't.

Tomorrow I hope I have the time to translate a part of Enriques' paper, where he also applies his principle of degeneration.

@BakerStreet: Thank you a lot.

You are welcome. I will try to ask advice from some friends of mine who are geometers about the traslation of some more difficult term.

Enriques devoted to the principle of degeneration an article in 1922, Il principio di degenerazione e la geometria sopra le curve algebriche., Math. Annalen LXXXV (1922), pp. 195-199.
As far as I know, it  hasn't been  translated in English.
As I said in the comments, I am not an expert of algebraic geometry, and in addition the language of the Italian school of algebraic geometry could be difficult, because it is often a particular language.
Anyway, I have translated the first part of the article, and I think the translation is overall correct, because I have searched for some references in Italian and in English, and I took some advice from some mathematicians I know.
In addition, I consulted also Wikipedia, Glossary of classical algebraic geometry
I hope my translation could be useful.  I could  also translate other parts of the article, if it could be useful, in instalments.., according to the time I have.
Below the translation of the first part of the article of Enriques, up to page 196, point $2$ included.
Enriques, F., The principle of degeneration and the geometry on algebraic curves

1. The Poncelet’s  principle of continuity has, in the theory of algebraic functions, an importance that mustn’t be reduced   – as
often happens- to  numerative issues only. By this fundamental
criterion the Lessons about the geometric theory of algebraic
equations and functions (of which I already published two volumes in
collaboration with Dr. Oscar Chisini, and of which we are preparing
the third one, that refers to  subjects dealt with in my university
courses of the years 1918-19 and 1919-20) are inspired. I take the
present notes from this volume.
Nöether and Lindemann already observed what the fundamental
propositions of the geometry on a plane curve $f$ of genus $p$ becomes
for continuity, when the curve, varying dependently on  a parameter,
acquires new multiple points: it deals with  an extension to the
not-adjunct or virtually adjunct curves of the theorems of the
ordinary  series cut$^1$ by the ordinary adjuncts. But the purpose of
these Notes is – in a way – the converse. Let $f$ vary, with general
moduli,  so that $p$ acquires double points, and becomes,
consequently, rational. Therefore, the geometry on the curve of genus $p$ -
with general moduli – would be reflected in the theory of linear
series$^2$ on the line; we want to show how the fundamental theorems of
that geometry are found, for any $p$. This way of proof has, in
principle, a heuristic value only,  and it is not worth  spending time
to transform it into a rigorous method of proof.  On the contrary it
is interesting to see how the degeneration of a curve of genus $p$
into a line, or into a curve of genus $<p$, provides the way to
establish rigourously some delicate points of the general doctrine,
which haven’t been dealt with satisfactorily, or have been dealt with only
through the Abelian integrals.
2. We observe, first of all, that, through the degeneration mentioned above (acquisition of $p$ of new double points), le $g^r_n$ on
a curve of genus $p$ reduces to the $g^r_n$ on a line with $p$ neutral
pairs, that is they provide only one condition to the groups of
these series which contain them; and these pairs – it useful to
notice this - can be assumed arbitrarily. In this sense, we can speak
of a line with $p$ pairs  as a curve of virtual genus $p$.
Having  said that, let see how the fundamental theorems of geometry on a curve
simply
are reflected in a line with $p$ pairs. […]


$^1$  The Italian term is serie segate, which literally means series sawed, it is an old term to say cut, intersected. 
$^2$  According to Alberto Conte,  Ciro Ciliberto, La scuola di geometria algebrica italiana, Enc. Treccani, 2004 
“A linear series is a family of ‘groups of points’ (presently called ‘divisors’) cut on the curve, by the hypersurfaces of a linear system”.

Thanks, it seems that Enriques left his "principle of degeneration" indeed heuristical. This is also remarked by Zariski in his Theory and applications of holomorphic functions, see page 2. A little remark on footnote 2: On a fixed scheme or variety $X$ a linear series is given by a family of codim 1 subvarieties which appear as so called effective divisors. So this is only a family of varying "groups of points" in specific case $X$ beeing a curve, so 1 dimensional.

Zariski remarked is quoted essay that whenever Enriques reasoned about "continuously varying family" then when picking two members $V, V_0$ of it ("$V$ degenerates to $V_0$") then he tacitly assumed - at least that's how I understood Zariki's elaboration there - that there exist a continuous proper (surjective?) map $f:V \to V_0$. Once assumed this, connectedness principle it a trivial consequence from topology. But existence of such $f$ is at formal level not trivial. Eg, in realm of smooth manifolds one need to argue via flows produced from appropriate vector fields.

@user267839
You are welcome. I added  footnote 2 because it refers specifically to what means hystorically 'linear series' for Enriques and the Italian school, as it is not granted that the meaning of terms of the Italian school are the same as nowadays, and the authors of the article are experts of the language of the Italian school.

...and by the way it seems that this resolved my question in prev comments about the role of the curve: The curve in the excerpt you translated in comments before is seemingly considered as those where the varying divisors live, so there he talks about divisors on this fixed curve.

@user267839 I'm happy this solved your question, thank you for accepting my answer.
